# Is it possible to charge a li-ion battery with brushless motors?

Tags: battery-charging, brushless-dc-motor, electricity

Can I charge a li-ion battery pack with the help of extra brushless motors(with a rectifier) attached to the front wheels of my electric skateboard. Will it work? Anything that I should know before doing this? And also if I sent the power coming from the motors into the battery through a BMS, will it charge the batteries properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey chris.thanks for replying. I don't wanna brake and regenerate but instead I wanna regenerate powered while I am riding the electric skateboard. Will it work if I attach two extra motors on the front wheels? And for the record, the BMS will not let the battery get charged if it is already at its maximum.

Comment: Can it work? probably! Will what you have work, no idea. No schematic, not judgement. If it does work though, it will act as a brake.

Comment: @Trevor why would it act as a brake?

Comment: EEK this is an electric skateboard.... NO it wont work. Worse because efficiency is always less than 100%, the battery will last even less time.

Comment: Because if you take energy out of a generator it acts to brake the generator. Energy has to come FROM somewhere.

Comment: @Trevor my idea was like- the motors would spin while I ride my board and they would generate some power which hopefully I'll be able to put back in the battery.

Comment: Sorry life does not work like that. They will just act as brakes.  So you will slow down when not driving with the other motors, and the latter will consume more EXTRA energy than you get back from the generator.

Comment: @user167195 167195, even with the motor well attached to the wheel, the effort of charging the batteries would keep your wheels to run so freely. The motor would put RESISTENCE to the wheels' movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking about "free energy", or, collecting "wasted" energy from the movement of the board, forget about it, because it's impossible.

If you're thinking about collecting some energy (even if it actually brakes the board's movement), the answer is **theoretically, yes**.

But I'm sorry to say that building this would be very difficult, or even impossible. The mechanical assembling would be critical; you would have to use gears to adjust the rotation of the motor. It could make harm to your equipment. And you would collect so little energy at all that it would be practically no gain.

There's no way for an amateur building a KERS system.

> Anything that I should know before doing this?

Yes, there are a lot of things that you can learn about this, the internet is full of tutorials about electronic, free energy, etc. I think that as soon as you learn more things, you'll become suddenly aware that this project is not worth your efforts.

Comment: I spent a week doing research on internet. I found a lot of videos where people use rectifiers to get a DC current out of a brushless motor and they power a light bulb or something like that, atleast I know it works, but I am not sure whether I will be able to charge a li-ion battery pack with this idea, that too when the motors are generating power when attached to from wheels and spinning in an electric skateboard.

Comment: OP is not thinking about a KERS system...  but free energy harvesting. There is a big difference.

Comment: @Trevor Sure! I didn't realized that he was aiming at the impossible. I edited the post.

Comment: Re, "building this would be very difficult"  Depends what "this" is.  If the goal is to make the skateboard go farther on a charge, then "difficult" is not the right word:  It's theoretically impossible.  But, if the goal is steal some energy from the skateboard to power an electronic device, then there's no reason that has to be any more "difficult" than the generator light that I used to have on my bicycle when I was a kid.  http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00KRtEbdasgzFI/Best-Dynamo-Light-for-Your-Bicycle.jpg

Comment: @james It's easy to connect a generator to a bike's wheel because the generator's can be easily fixed in the bike in order to its axe to touch the wheel. My grandpa still had and used to show me, in 80's, the generator he used in his bike in the 30's. When I said "very difficult" I was talking about fixing this would-be device to an electrical skateboard, where probably there would not be space to attach such device.